# Word or phrase that works for both "Yard Sale" and "Garage Sale"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Yard sales occur in the yard, while garage sales occur in the garage. But both accomplish the same thing: selling personal belongings from your home to the general public.

What word or phrase works for both? I see both of them used inter-changeably all the time, but it seems wrong.

I thought "Home Sale", but that could easily be mistaken for selling the home itself.

## Example:

> "I need to go find a *[word or phrase]* and look for a bike."

Comment: "Yard sale" -- a garage sale can also be called a yard sale, in most cases.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, it's that "most cases" part I'm looking around though.

Comment: The one place where a garage sale isn't also a yard sale is when the garage door is closed and  you enter through the side door.  (Well, that and when the garage is really a storage locker.)

Comment: I have never ***ever*** been to a garage sale that was solely contained in the garage.  I've been to plenty of yard sales that have stuff in the garage as well.  They are basically interchangeable.  What is it you think people might say, "Oh, it's a garage sale?! I don't go to garage sales, only yard sales."  But if you want to make your own distinction then call it a yard sale if any part of it takes place on the grass.  And call it a garage sale if it only takes place in the garage or a little out into the driveway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  I don't think there is anything wrong with **Garage Sale** or **Yard Sale** if you do not have a yard or a garage.

**Evolving Language:** All that really matters with words is that those reading the words know what to expect !  Our language evolves, sometimes by adding words and sometimes by changing the meaning of words.

**Meaning not necessarily 'from':**  keep in mind that both of these words don't necessarily mean "things from garage" but also "**near the sidewalk**"

Lots of other words could work...  but **are they more or less likely to be understood?**

- **sidewalk-sale**  (might this be confused with a crafts-person selling homemade goods in a public square or street fair)
- **estate sale**  People might use this interchangeably but it would be nice to have this mean more when someone dies and more than cast-offs are being sold and often access is given to inside portions of the home
- **junk-sale** or **spring-cleaning sale**  might work although it might not be spring and 'junk' isn't the best marketing
- **moving sale** might be good marketing suggesting maybe some good stuff might be there based on downsizing.  But, if not true it might be a slightly anti-social bait and switch ?
- **downsizing sale**  ... first guess for me would be this meant a business not a residence.

Long and short - **Is there a pertinent misconception with *garage* sale ? Is there a bait and switch ?**

IF **garage sale** most clearly conveys that you're looking to go by a place where an individual homeowner is hoping to sell some surplus items ,  why not use it?

Many words stay in the language to refer to a different technology use:

"**dialing**" still being used to press numbers on a phone 30 years past the dial interface.  Perhaps it is gradually giving way to "enter" and "call button" - yet still hasn't lost it's use entirely

"**keyboards**" on a glass phone interface are keyboard abstractions but, not quite boards.

I'm sure there are better examples.

Answer (score 5):

***[Garage sale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garage_sale)***  and yard sale are often used as synonyms:

> A garage sale (also known as a yard sale, tag sale, moving sale and by many other names[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garage_sale)) is an informal event for the sale of used goods by private individuals, in which sellers are not required to obtain business licenses or collect sales tax (though, in some jurisdictions, a permit may be required).

(Wikipedia)

Comment: It makes no sense though. Suppose someone's having a yard sale and they don't even have a garage? If anything, I would have expected "Garage Sale" to redirect to "Yard Sale", but Wikipedia redirects them the other way around :-/ "Tag Sale" is pretty abstract enough for the purpose though.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense. Why does it matter to customers if it’s a *garage* or a *yard* sale ? Do customers care? I can see why the terms have become synonymous.

Comment: @JerryD - It only makes "no sense" if you're overthinking it. Haven't you ever "dialed" a phone number? Asked for a "glass of water" and been given a plastic cup? _Tag sale_ is abstract enough, but it's also more of a [regionalism](https://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_58.html), so a lot of people may not know what you're talking if you say it. I'd be inclined to recommend [rummage sale](https://www.thespruce.com/difference-between-secondhand-sales-1313689), if the use of _yard sale_ or _garage sale_ is that vexing for you.

Comment: I think *garage sale* has to do with the idea that people tend to move the stuff they don't want in the house anymore out into the garage, and when the garage gets too full they have a *garage sale* to get rid of it.  That same stuff might get displayed out in the yard the day of the sale so people call it a *yard sale*.  The people coming to the sale might "rummage" through all that stuff looking for bargains and thus call it a *rummage sale.*"  (Three names for the same thing based on how you look at it.)

Comment: As an aside though: I tend to connote a rummage sale with a fund raiser that gets held at a church or school etc and not at somebody's house selling stuff out of that house.  I've never heard of a *tag sale*-  What? Are you selling tags or actual stuff?

Comment: @Jim - I lived in Connecticut for a few years, and _everyone_ called them ["tag sales"](https://news.hamlethub.com/bethel/events/46898-the-5th-annual-bethel-community-tag-sale-planned-for-may-5) out there. It's just another name for the same thing. I'm not sure where the phrase comes from; perhaps it's because people add a tag to indicate the price?

Comment: In UK/Ireland we don’t really use these terms. I hear them on American TV (well except tag sale - I’ve never heard that one before this question) so people understand them. We do have jumble sales (and car-boot sales) which a kinda synonymous.